# How to get default payment method from Stripe invoice?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am listening to Stripe's `invoice.payment_failed` webhook with my web app and I would like to get the `default_payment_method` from each invoice but for some reason it always returns nothing but an empty array!

When I query for a Stripe `invoice` on the command line and expand on the `default_payment_method` like this...

```
Stripe::Invoice.retrieve('in_3K6dIY2KgYRkshw2LAzya63P', :expand => "default_payment_method")
```

...I also get empty arrays. This surprises me because **all** my Stripe customers do have a default payment method associated with them.

What am I missing here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

There are three independent places a default payment method can be set. From more specific to less specific they go :

- `invoice.default_payment_method` (which you are looking at)
- `subscription.default_payment_method`
- `customer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method`

Stripe charges the most specific one if it's set. When reading from the API, those values don't inherit from the level above, they can all be set individually, if they are not set explicitly then they are `null`. So that's why you see it as `null` on the Invoice level.

Instead you likely want to look at the Subscription object or the Customer object(and can leverage the expand feature for that), depending on how you built your integration and which one it sets.

Overall though, you probably *actually* want the PaymentMethod used in the invoice payment though? That would be from the `last_payment_error`.

```
inv = Stripe::Invoice.retrieve({
   id: 'in_1K8iiKJoUivz182DMzSkuBgp',
   expand: ["customer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method",
       "subscription.default_payment_method",
       "payment_intent"]
  }
)

print("invoice : #{inv.default_payment_method} \n")
print("subscription : #{inv.subscription.default_payment_method} \n")
print("customer : #{inv.customer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method} \n")
print("failed charge : #{inv.payment_intent.last_payment_error.payment_method} \n")
```

Comment: On top of what's said above, to get the default payment method, you'll also need to read `default_source` on `customer`, `invoice` or `subscription`. Stripe's own Dashboard uses the legacy api when changing these settings. When _reading_ these properties, always check both! More [details here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/issues/2631)